# Meteor http get retrieving only a subset of headers

Tags: meteor, http-headers, sockjs

In my Meteor (1.2) application, I make a **client-side** HTTP.get call over https to a remote server supporting CORS.

```
var getUrl= "https://remoteserver/;
HTTP.call('GET', getUrl , {}, function (error, response) {
    console.log (response);
}
```

Now, the issue is that **set-cookie** string is **present** in HTTP headers of the response of such HTTP call in **Chrome's DevTools' Network tab**.

However when I call console.log (response) , they're not included. Actually only these 3 properties are printed in **response['headers']**:

- Content-Type
- cache-control
- last-modified

Digging more in, I found out on [Meteor Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_onconnection) that

> Cookies are deliberately excluded from the headers as they are a security risk for this transport. For details and alternatives, see the SockJS documentation.

Now, on the linked [SockJS docs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node#authorisation), it says that

> Basically - cookies are not suited for SockJS model. If you want to authorise a session - provide a unique token on a page, send it as a first thing over SockJS connection and validate it on the server side. In essence, this is how cookies work.

I found this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851603/socket-io-not-sending-cookies-in-the-handshake-causing-the-request-to-stall) about sockJS but it looks outdated an not specific to Meteor.

The remote server expects me to use cookie-set header, so I have no choice. Also, for established scalability reasons, the HTTP.call must be done client-side (server-side was not an issue at all)
What solution / workaround can I adopt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package looks to be designed to help in situations like this, though I have not used it:

https://atmospherejs.com/dandv/http-more